# Why is AWS SNS treating 404 response from subscriber as successful?

Tags: amazon-sns

I'm having a hard time understanding how SNS handles response messages. My SNS subscriber is a page that might go down or simply return a 4xx error.

For some reason though, it seems that SNS is treating requests that return 4xx error codes as successful.

How can I make it fail when the response code is 4xx and not only 5xx?

From the logs we can see that the subscriber is returning a status code 404 Not found, but despite that, the status of the request is still SUCCESS.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "fd746e97153916fd99bba*********",
        "messageId": "be666c50-8de5-594b-9e77-*********",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:060758096283:*********,
        "timestamp": "2021-11-23 14:21:23.778"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "ef278086-2a70-5512-a191-da90d1534d24",
        "redrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:*********:*********-DLQ\"}",
        "destination": "*********/subscriber.php",
        "providerResponse": "Not Found",
        "dwellTimeMs": 80,
        "attempts": 1,
        "statusCode": 404
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

This is causing me issues with monitoring, as It's very hard to know if my requests are actually successful or not without manually looking them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNS's job is to deliver a message to the endpoint. If the endpoint responds with a valid status code (not a 5XX failure), it considers the *delivery* of the message successful. How that message is responded to is up to the receiving API.

To be precise, only status codes outside of the range 200 - 499 will be considered as a failures and retried according to your retry policy as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html. Once the max number of retries has been exhausted, the message will be delivered to a DLQ if one is configured.