# SNS, how to guard against silently losing notifications on 404

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, amazon-sns

This is a follow up question to [Why is AWS SNS treating 404 response from subscriber as successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082761/why-is-aws-sns-treating-404-response-from-subscriber-as-successful)

I understand SNS will treat 200-4xx responses of subscribing HTTP endpoints as successfully handled and will not attempt redelivery.

This however seems to introduce the issue where a missing subscribing endpoint (for example, one that was mistakenly removed from a production environment) will go unnoticed and will cause notifications to go silently unhandled: Most web frameworks will default to returning 404 in such cases, SNS will in turn interpret that as successfully handled and will never retry or move the notification to the DLQ.

Is there some obvious workaround, best practice or approach to monitoring that will remedy this?